# Export bootstrap-table data not working Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, excel, internet-explorer, bootstrap-table

When clicking the export button to export table data to an excel file, nothing happens on Internet Explorer. The functionality works fine on Google Chrome and Firefox, however a lot of our users are still stuck in Internet Explorer land and are unwilling to budge.

Does a work around exist to get this functionality working? Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Relevant code:

```
%table.class_name{data: {"show-export" => "true", "export-types" => ['excel']}}
```